# Display the hash of a file

Tags: dired

I would like to view the (MD5) hash of the file at point in a `dired` buffer.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run shell command `md5` on file-at-point in dired, use `! md5` (Here `!` runs `dired-do-shell-command`.

Comment: IME the command is called `md5sum`